# How to get queryset i need?

Tags: django

i have 2 models

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to='users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tasks',
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        to='TaskCategory',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tasks',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    difficult = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=(MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01')),),
    )


class TaskCategory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        to='users.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='task_categories',
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
    )
```

i want to get this query(get top 3 category of most difficults sum and next one to sum of anothers):

[
{
"category__name": "Food",
"category_sum": "12477.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Shopping",
"category_sum": "3214.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Movie",
"category_sum": "2590.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Anothers",
"category_sum": "2000.00"
}

]

i make this queryset, but i dont know how make queryset i want:

```
Task.objects.values('category__name').annotate(
                category_sum=Coalesce(
                    Sum('difficult'),
                    0,
                    output_field=DecimalField()
                )
            ).filter(
              category__isnull=False
             ).order_by('-category_sum')
```

[
{
"category__name": "Food",
"category_sum": "12477.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Shopping",
"category_sum": "3214.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Movie",
"category_sum": "2590.00"
},
{
"category__name": "Sport",
"category_sum": "1000.00"
}
{
"category__name": "Home",
"category_sum": "1000.00"
}

]

Answer (score 0):

If you want limit queryset to 3 rows just add [:3] like:

```
Task.objects.values('category__name').annotate(
            category_sum=Coalesce(
                Sum('difficult'),
                0,
                output_field=DecimalField()
            )
        ).filter(
          category__isnull=False
         ).order_by('-category_sum')[:3]
```

that's all

More examples about slicing lists in python: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/list-slicing